# upgrade openssl for old version xampp

Tags: apache, openssl, xampp

I am trying to enable TLS 1.1 on my xampp apache server, but it seems like the version of OpenSSL is too old for that. (Error: SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1')

Can anyone help me how I can upgrade OpenSSL? or something easier approach? I need to keep PHP version as 5.3.1.

My configuration is Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I don't think my question can go under that. It is about xampp and sitting under Windows 7. And also it is related with programming or development.

Answer (score 1):

Download the 1.0.2k zip file from this site.
https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/
Extract the files.
Stop the Apache service.
Make a backup of these 3 files in C:\xampp\apache\bin
ssleay32.dll
libeay32.dll
openssl.exe
Copy the same 3 files from the extract files location to C:\xampp\apache\bin
Start the Apache service.